# How to set all properties for viewer.getCamera() in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I use the markup extension for Autodesk forge. When i want to show markups with separate layers, i get camera positions and rotate model with that position. But when i move model in show mode and after when i want to see another markup layer, the model positions changes. How can i fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `const viewState = viewer.getState({ viewport: true })` to capture current camera statue instead, and restore it via `viewer.restoreState( viewState )`